# If an Order By clause is specified, are identity values consistent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following code:

```
declare @StatementTable table 
                        (
                            ID int identity not null,
                            StatementText nvarchar(max) not null
                        );

insert into @StatementTable (StatementText)
    select
        StatementToExecute
    from
        dbo.MyTable
    order by
        MyColumn
```

As long as the `dbo.MyTable` does not change and `MyColumn` is unique, will the ID values in the `@StatementTable` table variable be consistent from execution to execution?

In other words, does providing an `order by` clause guarantee consistent order of insert?

[ORDER BY Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> When used with a SELECT...INTO statement to insert rows from another source, the ORDER BY clause does not guarantee the rows are inserted in the specified order.

If it matters, I'm on SQL Server 2017...

Comment: @avery_larry yes it does! Was having a heck of a time coming up with the right search terms!

Comment: It was tough.  I googled "sql insert order by identity"